# directed edges in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, programming-languages, greedy-algorithms

Undirected graph is given which has M edges and N vertices we have to convert every edge from u−v to u→v or v→u such that the total outdegree of every vertex is even.

For example, consider a graph which has the edges 1-2, 1-3, 2-4, 3-4. We can direct it as 1→2, 1→3, 2←4, 3←4, so outdegrees of 1,2,3,4 are respectively 2,0,0,2 which are all even.

Which method or algorithm is suited for least time complexity? M and N are between 1 and 100,000.

Comment: Please credit the original source of the problem.

Comment: It might be not possible - consider cycle $C_3$